# Page Footer is not showing in first Page if the sub report is having two pages data in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a report as like in the attached report.png .

[image]

In that report I have two sub reports in the report  header section.

If the second sub report have more than one page data in it ie two pages , then the page footer section is not getting displayed in the first Page.
But in the second page I can see the Page footer.

I have tried the by removing the keep together ,but it’s not working.

Can anyone suggest some idea?

Comment: There's no reason for the behaviour you report. Is there any suppress rule on Page Footer?

Comment: No there is no suppress rule.I feel the second sub report is getting merged with the page footer as it have second page data

Comment: have you tried putting both subreports in Report Footer (Report Footer A and B)?

Comment: Thank you so much that seems to be working,but now another issue occurs the second sub report report header is not showing in second page .I can see the header in the first page but not in the second page.

Comment: wich "keep together" did you uncheck? There's one in Main Report -> Report Header, one in Main Report -> Subreport Object, one in Subreport -> Report Header .. did you remove all of these?